# Dell Latitude E5520 Touchpad fails to work after upgrade to Win 10

Tags: touchpad

Upgraded to Windows 10 1903 
The Touchpad fails to work although a USB mouse works
Tried Win 7 and 8 drivers too from DELL but NO success
Any help appreciated

Comment: There are a number of driver issues with v. 1903. Downgrade to v. 1809, last stable release.

Comment: Thank you.
Tried the down grade trick
Still not working.
Anyway to modify the driver?
Seems to be related to the Tpad utility

Comment: If you have a backup image, save your data and revert to Windows 7, then upgrade to the somewhat-safer Windows 10 v. 1809... issues are *still* being fond in that, though.